# Excel Runtime Error 438 Object does not support property or method

Tags: excel, vba

Sheet "Symbol Editor" is the only sheet in the workbook.**

```
        Sub AssembleSymbol()    
            Worksheets("Symbol Editor").Shapes.SelectAll
            Selection.Group
        End Sub
```

Before the subroutine AssembleSymbol() is run, there are 3 shapes inserted into the Symbol Editor, then the subroutine is run and I get:

> "Excel Runtime Error 438 Object does not support property or method"

Even though I get an error, when you look at the worksheet all shapes are selected and grouped.

The rationale for grouping the Shapes is to save the shapes as 1 collective symbol along with their "relative" positions, to one another, in a "SymbolLibrary" to be used in future, user-defined, "displays"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

### `TypeName` With Shapes

- Most likely the shapes were grouped already when this error would occur.

```vb
Sub AssembleSymbolOrig()
    Worksheets("Symbol Editor").Shapes.SelectAll
    MsgBox TypeName(Selection), vbInformation, "TypeName"
    If TypeName(Selection) = "DrawingObjects" Then Selection.Group
End Sub

Sub AssembleSymbolStudy()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Symbol Editor")
    Dim shps As Shapes: Set shps = ws.Shapes
    
    Dim TN As String
    
    Select Case shps.Count
    Case 0
        TN = TypeName(Selection)
        MsgBox "There are no shapes ('" & TN & "').", vbInformation
    Case 1
        shps.SelectAll
        TN = TypeName(Selection)
        If TN = "GroupObject" Then
            Selection.Ungroup
            MsgBox "Ungrouped a group ('" & TN & "').", vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox "One shape selected ('" & TN & "').", vbInformation
        End If
    Case Is > 1
        shps.SelectAll
        TN = TypeName(Selection)
        If TN = "DrawingObjects" Then
            Selection.Group
            MsgBox "Grouped all shapes ('" & TN & "').", vbInformation
        End If
    End Select
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your answers.  Microsoft used to publish a large poster of the Excel object Model, for reference. does anyone have any idea  where I might find this on the internet?